# PHP regex with \s in it is not working

Tags: php, regex

so I have this code:

```
$body = '$var = \'VALUE\';';
$matches = array();
preg_match("/\$var\s*=\s*('|\")(.*)('|\");/", $body, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

However, it reveals that $matches is empty...

Why is that the case? When I tried the regex on http://regex101.com/ it worked. Is it because of the \s I used in the regex? (I'm trying to match whitespace characters using it)

Comment: FYI In PHP you should use single quotes for your regex strings - they don't try to interpret the escaped characters. `'\n'` will be `\n` but `"\n"` will be a newline.

Comment: escape it when you use normal quotes. Example: `"\\s"` or change the quotes: `'\s'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"\$"` is a string containing a literal `$`. In regex, a literal `$` means "end of string" (or "end of line" with the appropriate modifier).

You need to use `\\\$`, or use single-quotes instead of double-quotes around your string.

Another option is NOWDOC:

```
preg_match(<<<'REGEX'
/\$var\s*=\s*(['"])(.*)\1;/
REGEX
, $body, $matches);
```

It looks nicer with syntax highlighting, I promise!

[image: highlight]

Comment: ... and that's why we use single quotes in RegExp patterns; keeping track of a gazillion backslashes is nobody's idea of fun.

Comment: Heh - yeah, NOWDOC's solid but I find it harder to read ... I start thinking I'm writing STDIN in C :)

Comment: Not all editors support NOWDOC/HEREDOC syntax highlighting :(