# In PHP, how can you have quotes around a variable like this?

Tags: php, wordpress

I saw this code snippet somewhere, wordpress related stuff:

```
$theme_root = get_theme_root();
$files_array = glob("$theme_root/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

It's the `"$theme_root/*"` part I don't understand. Why quotes around variables?

Why wouldn't the code above instead be written like this:

```
$theme_root = get_theme_root();
$files_array = glob($theme_root . "/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

Comment: Both work. The author just chose the first way over the second (and other options as well).

Comment: Read the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: A useful side-note: only double quotes work around variables. `'$theme_root/*'` won't work.

Comment: @EduardLuca Double quotes and the heredoc syntax both work.

Comment: @kapa true. I meant in terms of quotes. Heredoc is something entirely different :)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I hope I won't be expelled from this site after bringing up such a dark practice :).

Comment: @kapa If they expel you, [I'd be next](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764830/php-regex-with-s-in-it-is-not-working/22764876#22764876)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Because it works" is a dangerously common reason for doing things in PHP... In this case, it's no big deal, but in other places this principle can be very dangerous.

Anyway, optimally, it should be:

```
$theme_root . '/*'
```

Note the use of single-quotes - these are faster to parse because PHP doesn't have to look for variable to interpolate or escape sequences to handle.

That said, however, "fixes" like this are basically micro-optimisation and not something you should dedicate time to.

Answer (score 0):

When you use double quotes, PHP tries to interpret variables inside the string

```
$test = 'aaa';
echo "test:$test"; //returns 'test:aaa';
echo 'test:$test'; //returns 'test:test';
```

This syntax could be interesting because it is quite clear, but it is slower if you don't use variables inside the string :

```
echo "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"; //slower
echo 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'; //faster
```